# what google map plug-in is used on this website?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Can someone tell me what kind of plug-in is used for map functionality on this website?

http://nextride.brampton.ca/RealTime.aspx

This is what page source looks like for the script reference.

```
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.1&amp;sensor=false" 
type="text/javascript"></script>


    function InitMap(){ var MapControl2 = new OrbitalMap(); MapControl2.BusZoomLevel = 11; 
MapControl2.CenterLat = 43.696289; MapControl2.CenterLong = -79.773865; 
MapControl2.MapContainer = 'MapControl1_Container'; MapControl2.MapRefreshInterval = '60'; 
MapControl2.MapMargin = '0.01'; MapControl2.MinZoomLevel = 10; MapControl2.ProviderUrl = 
'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.1&sensor=false'; MapControl2.RefreshTimeout = 
'15'; MapControl2.RouteZoomLevel = 11; MapControl2.SelectedStop = 0; 
MapControl2.StopZoomLevel = 14; MapControl2.ZoomLevel = 13; 
MapControl2.EnableStatusOnBusIconsInMap = 'False'; MapControl2.ApplicationRootDirectory = 
''; MapControl2.AccessKey = ''; MapControl2.CssClass = ''; MapControl2.SkinID = ''; 
MapControl2.ToolTip = ''; MapControl2.ClientID = 'ctl00_mainPanel_MainPanel1_MapControl2'; 
MapControl2.ID = 'MapControl2'; MapControl2.TemplateSourceDirectory = '/Controls'; 
MapControl2.AppRelativeTemplateSourceDirectory = '~/Controls/'; MapControl2.UniqueID = 
'ctl00$mainPanel$MainPanel1$MapControl2'; MapControl2.InitMap();} window.onload = 
InitMap//]]>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MarkerManager v3.  The rest of it appears to be using standard API 3 javascript

Answer (score 0):

It's the Google maps api v3 obviously; or what do you want to know....?

Comment: i can see that but is it using any jquery-plugin as well?

Comment: They use JQuery 1.3.2 for the Live-clock in the top-right corner; which seems to be a bit of a overkill to me....

Comment: one of the line says var MapControl2 = new OrbitalMap(). what is OrbitalMap. I am sure it is a customized map or some kind of plug-in.

Comment: OrbitalMap is their own javascript wrapping up calls to the API: http://nextride.brampton.ca/WebResource.axd?d=EaB8msPW5krWQwriTUbKT9O-G_1jYkxphdxwvCVpBPjuWSlQxQyglbaXPt_1oGqviQz40T9ve2Ji2ZpQxUWjRZUP2EIncfkde6ehA7sKEgHUuA8JVdOU9L6GYap86Cg5GeErxZt7f3AJKYWTW4aXOsat6wo1&t=634522192200000000